# How to stop outer block from inner block

Tags: ruby, command-line

I try to implement search function which looks for occurrence for particular `keyword`, but if `--max` options is provided it will print only some particular number of lines.

```
def search_in_file(path_to_file, keyword)
  seen = false
  File::open(path_to_file) do |f|
    f.each_with_index do |line, i|
      if line.include? keyword

        # print path to file before only if there occurence of keyword in a file
        unless  seen
          puts path_to_file.to_s.blue
          seen = true
        end

        # print colored line
        puts "#{i+1}:".bold.gray + "#{line}".sub(keyword, keyword.bg_red)


        break if i == @opt[:max]  # PROBLEM WITH THIS!!! 

      end



    end
  end
  puts "" if seen
end
```

I try to use `break` statement, but when it's within `if ... end` block I can't break out from outer `each_with_index` block.

If I move `break` outside `if ... end` it works, but it's not what I want.

How I can deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to move that `break if i == @opt[:max]` line out if the `if` block? Btw your current implementation has the problem that it does not stop if the line with `@opt[:max]` number doesn't include the keyword. You have to change that anyway.

Comment: The point is,  to check only lines where occurrence was found and stop when maximum reached. If I will do it in your way it will count all line, 10 for example, and stops. What I want is to count lines only with occurrence.

Comment: @spickermann your comment indirectly pointed me to where real problem is. Actually I do comparison on the wrong variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to implement it in your code as I'm still learning Ruby, but you can try catch and throw to solve this.

```
def search_in_file(path_to_file, keyword)
  seen = false
  catch :limit_reached do
  #put your code to look in file here...
  throw :limit_reached if i == @opt[:max] #this will break and take you to the end of catch block
```

Something like this already exist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286861/how-to-break-from-nested-loops-in-ruby)

Comment: Actually, the problem was not with how I break out of block, but with how I count lines and check condition to break.